# Unable to merge dex in 1.0.60 in android 3.0 while using facebook-login.aar

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook-login, dex

I am trying to use **facebook-login.aar** for facebook login implementation in my app. But whenever I try to run the app it gives this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex in 1.0.60
```

I commented the //    `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])` part in dependencies then it does not show the error. **I tried all the questions related to the DexArchiveMergerException but none worked for me. :(**

Comment: did u try clean project??

Comment: Yeah I did: 
I delete the .gradle
I delete all build dir
I clean the project 
I rebuild it
but it gives the error I mentioned when I tried to run the app.